# Aggregate function is return incorrect value when joining more table

Tags: sql-server, join, aggregate-functions

I am getting the Total sale using the following query.

```
SELECT SUM([B].[TotalSale])  
FROM [dbo].[BookingDetail] [BF] WITH (READPAST)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Booking] [B] WITH (READPAST) ON [B].[BookingDetailID] = [BF].[ID]
WHERE [BF].[MarketID] = '2'
```

I want to add another column to get the Gross Sale .
For that I have to make a join with another table called AirTraveler.

But once I add a new table to the query

```
SELECT 
SUM([B].[TotalSale])  ,
SUM(CASE WHEN [B].[TravelSectorID] = 3 AND [B].[BookingStatusID] IN (16, 20, 22, 23)  THEN COALESCE([B].[TotalSale], 0.0)
         WHEN ([B].[TravelSectorID] = 1 AND [B].[IsDomestic] = 1 AND CONVERT(varchar, [AT].[FareDetails].query('string(/AirFareInfo[1]/PT[1])')) = 'FlightAndHotel') THEN [AT].[TotalSale] 
         ELSE 0 END) AS [GrossSale]
FROM [dbo].[BookingDetail] [BF] WITH (READPAST)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Booking] [B] WITH (READPAST) ON [B].[BookingDetailID] = [BF].[ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  [dbo].[AirTraveler] [AT] WITH(READPAST) ON [B].[ID] = [AT].[BookingID]
WHERE [BF].[MarketID] = '2'
```

it is giving incorrect result of [TotalSale] .the aggregate functions return wrong values because there may be multiple AirTraveler per Booking ID, which is correct. What can I do to solve the aggregate function problem?

I am actually stuck.

I am using SQL Server .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely your total is correct even before this because `bookingdetail` has many rows? Anyway, the solution is to use `WHERE EXISTS` rather than joining.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid :  using WHERE EXISTS , how am I going to get the value of [AT].[FareDetails].query('string(/AirFareInfo[1]/PT[1])') . Could you please edit the aforementioned query.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested or anything, but when you are joining to a lower level table that causes a header table to double count, you can pre-aggregate it before it joins

This is probably missing some opening/closing brackets and aliases but hopefully you can work it out

```
SELECT 
SUM([B].[TotalSale])  ,
SUM(CASE WHEN [B].[TravelSectorID] = 3 
AND [B].[BookingStatusID] IN (16, 20, 22, 23)  
THEN COALESCE([B].[TotalSale], 0.0)
         WHEN ([B].[TravelSectorID] = 1 AND [B].[IsDomestic] = 1 
         THEN [AT].[TotalSale] 
         ELSE 0 END) AS [GrossSale]
FROM [dbo].[BookingDetail] [BF] WITH (READPAST)
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Booking] [B] WITH (READPAST) ON [B].[BookingDetailID] = [BF].[ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
(
SELECT BookingID,  SUM(CASE WHEN 
CONVERT(varchar(50), [FareDetails].query('string(/AirFareInfo[1]/PT[1])')) 
= 'FlightAndHotel') THEN [TotalSale] ELSE 0 END) TotalSale
FROM [dbo].[AirTraveler] [AT] WITH(READPAST) 
GROUP BY BookingID
) AT
ON [B].[ID] = [AT].[BookingID]
WHERE [BF].[MarketID] = '2'
```

Also I gave your varchar cast a size - I think if you don't do this it'll be 1 so your case is never true